# Не совпадают ответы

Tags: c#

По условию, после ввода a, производится расчет по этим двум формулам, ответ должен совпасть. Где я допустил ошибку? Ответы не совпадают.

[image: Формулы]

```
    double a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    double z = 1 - (1 / 4) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(2 * a),2) + Math.Cos(2 * a);
    double z1 = Math.Pow(Math.Cos(a),2) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos(a), 4);
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(z);
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(z1);
```

Comment: Округлять надо......либо тип соблюсти `(1 - (1 / (double)4).....` т.к. целочисленное деление 1 на 4 будет 0, а не 0.25

Comment: Смущает `double a = Convert.ToInt32(...);`. Вы уверены, что `a` должно быть целым?

Comment: @DmitryD. нет, не уверен, но в итоге-то, благодаря Алексею, ответ совпал. Почему вас это смущает?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Целочисленное деление 1 на 4 будет 0, а не 0.25. Соответственно для получения ожидаемого результата приводите к нужному типу:

`(1/(double)4)`

http://ideone.com/kqEU38

Или же по совету @Pavel Mayorov  - писать сразу с нужным типом один из членов:
`(1 / 4.0)` или `(1.0 / 4)`

Comment: Каким образом поможет `(double)(1/4)`? Кажется, что всё равно сначала выполнится целочисленное `1/4`, а уже потом результат (т.е. ноль) приведётся к `double`?

Comment: @yeputons это я спросонья)

Comment: Зачем так сложно?! `(1 / 4.0)` или `(1.0 / 4)`

Comment: @PavelMayorov см. выше)) ...добавил в ответ.. Если есть желание - моете подредактировать).

Answer (score -3):

Сравните 2 варианта:

**1**:

```
double a = 22.22;
double z = 1 - (1 / 4) * pow(sin(2 * a),2) + cos(2 * a);
double z1 = pow(cos(a),2) + pow(cos(a), 4);
printf( "%f, %f\n", z,z1 );
```

Вывод:

```
1.897070, 1.848254
```

**2**:

```
double a = 22.22;
double z = 1 - 0.25 * pow(sin(2 * a),2) + cos(2 * a);
double z1 = pow(cos(a),2) + pow(cos(a), 4);
printf( "%f, %f\n", z,z1 );
```

Вывод:

```
1.848254, 1.848254
```

Ни на какие мысли не наводит? А если так?

```
printf( "%f, %f\n", (1.0/4), (double)(1/4) );
```